# Is there any result on approximating an arbitrary tree metric by an HST metric?

Tags: ds.algorithms, approximation-algorithms, embeddings

Is there any known result on approximating an arbitrary tree metric by an HST metric (or an Ultrametric)? What is the distortion? Thanks.

Comment: Not following: what's the difference between an HST metric and a general tree metric ?

Comment: An HST metric is a special tree metric. So we still want to embed a "hard" metric space into a simpler metric space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distortion of embedding any $n$-point metric in  ultrametric is at most $n-1$, and on the other hand, the distortion of embedding the path metric $P_n$ in ultrametric is at least $n-1$.

Similarly, if you are interested in probabilistic embedding, then by Fakcharoenphol, Rao, and Talwar result mentioned above, any $n$-point metric space probabilistically embeds in ultrametric with distortion $O(\log n)$. 
On the other hand, the distortion of probabilistically embedding $P_n$ in ultrametric is $\Omega(\log n)$.

Answer (score 3):

There is a classic [result](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/74347/06-journal.pdf) by Fakcharoenphol, Rao, and Talwar showing that any $n$ point metric space can be embedded into an HST metric with expected distortion $O(log\, n)$.

One should keep in mind that this result holds only for probabilistic embeddings, since there are metrics (such as the $n$-cycle) which will give you an $\Omega(n)$ distortion if you only accept deterministic embeddings.

Comment: Thanks. I knew the FRT result. Actually I was asking a different question. See the quesiton now. For some reason, the word "tree"  was deleted by the editor...I added it back now.